# Application crashes says : Access violation reading location 0xbaadf04d

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I m doing project in opencv... i m getting error like this

"Unhandled exception at 0x775a15ee in touch.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf04d."

the code is

```
using namespace std;

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     //declerations

    CvCapture *frame=0;
    IplImage *image=0;

    cvNamedWindow( "Image taken", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(2);
    frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(2);
    image = cvQueryFrame(frame);
    cvShowImage("Image taken", image);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cvCreateCameraCapture(2) – why 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(2);
```

with

```
frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
if (!frame) {
    puts("Couldn't detect a camera.");
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply that problem got resolved but i am having another problem the camera is getting on but  "image taken" is getting black so i made changes and the code is
 this is working fine may i know the reason

Comment: int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  //declerations
 
 CvCapture *frame=0;
 IplImage *image=0;
 for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
 frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
 //frame=cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
 
 if (!frame) {
  puts("Couldn't detect a camera.");
  return(1);
 }
 
 image = cvQueryFrame(frame);
 cvNamedWindow( "Image taken", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 cvShowImage("Image taken",image);
 cvWaitKey(1000);
 }
 cvReleaseImage(&image);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Don't hijack your own thread, if you have a different question unrelated to the current, feel free to ask another question in a new thread.

Comment: @MridulBirla What you probably want to do is poll camera in a loop. See [this article and code sample](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture).